# NodeJS req.body JSON there but no value

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

server.use(express.static('public'));
server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.post('/saveentry', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("Eintrag gespeichert");
});

server.listen(80, 'localhost');
```

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gästebuch</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="guestbook"></div>
        <input type="text" id="entry" name="entry">
        <button id="submit">Senden</button>

        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            var formData = {
                entry: $("#entry").val()
            }
            $('#submit').click(function() 
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/saveentry',
                    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                    dataType: "text",
                    contentType : "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the result in the console if I press "Senden": 
{ entry: '' }

How can I get the text entered in the form? What else can I try? I didn't find the solution online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should receive value from input inside callback function:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var formData = {
        entry: $("#entry").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/saveentry',
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        dataType: "text",
        contentType : "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```